# Не могу запарсить нужный мне сайт из-за ошибки 403 и блокировки доступа

Tags: python, python-3.x

Преподаватель дал задание - написать скрапер базы Интерпола. Взялся писать. Из моих инструментов:

1. requests
2. Beautiful Soup

Первая и единственная моя серьёзная проблема, с которой я столкнулся - блокировка доступа из-за слишком частых запросов. Что я пытался сделать, чтобы преодолеть эту проблему:

1. Прокси и рандомизация User-Agent - не помогло. Не хватает качественных и быстрых https-прокси.
2. Переписать запросы с использованием `requests.session` - не помогло. Всё также получаю бан за слишком частые запросы.

Резонный вопрос: что делать?

Comment: загружай страницу целиком. webkit

Comment: Наверное, не надо так часто их дергать?

Comment: а мне кажется там ловушка стоит на то чтоб не знагружали хтмлку без статики

Comment: @eri там такой алгоритм - за один поиск выводится максимум 160 разыскиваемых. Поэтому, я делаю сортировку начиная от 15-16 лет, заканчивая 99-100. За это отвечают параметры `/(current_age_mini)/29/(current_age_maxi)/30/`. Я создаю 85 потоков, каждый из которых вызывает парсер по конкретно определённым возрастным рамкам. А ещё на странице есть параметр `(offset)/9/`, который отвечает за номер страниц. offset 0 - первая страница, offset 9, вторая, и так далее(на странице по 9 разыскиваемых).Собсна, мне дают запарсить лишь первую страницу. При попытке обратиться ко второй - 403 на время.

Comment: «что делать?» — не отправлять запросы чаще одного в пять секунд :)

Comment: @andreymal тогда парсер будет работать минут 40.

Comment: Ну не год же :) Я однажды один сайтец четыре месяца парсил, и ничего, не умер))

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вам поможет sleep

```
from time import sleep
...
sleep(5)
...
```

Comment: Автору этот вариант не нравится

Comment: хотелось бы узнать чем, но ладно